Strictification of Pseudomonoids into Monoids
The strictification theorem for monoidal categories tells us that each monoidal category is monoidaly-equivalent to a strict monoidal category.
Does this generalise to pseudomonoids?
Are there known conditions on the background monoidal bicategory under which pseudomonoids become isomorphic (as pseudomonoids) to strict monoids?

This question has been asked on MathOverflow. Check there to see if one of the answers answers your question.

Hi @varkor! Thanks for your comment. The question and it's answers that you linked seem to only discuss coherence (not strictification). Whilst the proof I'm aware of for the strictification of monoidal categories makes heavy use of the coherence theorem, I don't see immediately why they will amount to the same question when extended to general pseudomonoids. Are questions about coherence and strictification really equivalent in the general setting? (I would have been surprised to hear they were).

It is definitely true that there are strictification results for pseudomonoids (indeed, more generally for weak algebras for a monad). I don't have the reference at hand but I believe they're written down by Steve Lack somewhere.

A very general answer to your question is Theorem 3.2 of Lack's paper "Codescent objects and coherence" available here. Pseudomonoids are (pseudo)algebras for a 2-monad and in "most" cases they can be strictified.
It is true that "coherence" is not always the same as "strictification," but the former is often used to prove the latter. There's a nice discussion of this here.
